# Asp.net get index Value of chart datapoint on mouse click having issue with postback method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, charts, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to get the index of a selected point on a chart with mouse click but I am not having any luck. I am trying to use the postBack function to get the data from the index like it showed in a example for chart interactivity, but everytime the postback method is called it clears the chart and does not appear to get the value properly. I have been searching for a solution but have not found one yet if anyone can help me fix this problem I would be super happy and have a small reward for who ever helps me solve this problem.

```
 namespace StockWebsite
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateFill(DropDownList1);
        dateFill(DropDownList2);
        DropDownList3.Items.Add("Daily");
        DropDownList3.Items.Add("Weekly");
        DropDownList3.Items.Add("Monthly");

        FlowChartfill();
    }

    protected void GetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadData();
    }

    protected void SymbolName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    public void DownloadData()
    {



        string csvData = null;
        string Span = "d";
        //d = Month -1//e= day//f = current year//a= month +1 //b= day//c = year
        if (DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text == "Daily")
        {
            Span = "d";

        }
        if (DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text == "Weekly")
        {
            Span = "w";

        }
        if (DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text == "Monthly")
        {
            Span = "m";

        }
        string month1 = Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex);
        string month2 = Convert.ToString(DropDownList2.SelectedIndex);
        string Temp = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + SymbolName.Text + "&d=" + month2 + "&e=" + TextBox3.Text + "&f=" + TextBox4.Text + "&g=" + Span + "&a=" + month1 + "&b=" + TextBox1.Text + "&c=" + TextBox2.Text + "&ignore=.csv";
        string FileRead;

        string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                csvData = web.DownloadString(Temp);
                csvData = csvData.Replace("Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close", "");
            }

            catch
            {

            }
        }
        if (csvData != null && csvData != "")
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path + "\\MyTest.txt", csvData);
        }

        //System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path + "\\MyTest.txt");
        //   while ((FileRead = file.ReadLine()) != null) //reads from file
        // {
        //     Remove1.Add(FileRead);
        // }
        // file.Close();
        // Remove1.Clear();



        List<stock> prices = YahooFinance.Parse(csvData);
        double Lowest = 0;
        foreach (stock price in prices) // finds lowest value to addjust priceing 
        {
            if (Lowest == 0)
            {
                Lowest = Convert.ToDouble(price.low);
            }
            if (Lowest > Convert.ToDouble(price.low))
            {
                Lowest = Convert.ToDouble(price.low);
            }
        }
        //  new double[] { Convert.ToDouble(price.low), Convert.ToDouble(price.high), Convert.ToDouble(price.Open), Convert.ToDouble(price.close) }
        Chart1.IsMapEnabled = true;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 2;
        Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 2;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = prices.Count + 20;
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = Lowest - 3;
        int i = prices.Count - 1;
        while (i > 0)
        {

            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(prices[i].date, Convert.ToDouble(prices[i].low), Convert.ToDouble(prices[i].high), Convert.ToDouble(prices[i].Open), Convert.ToDouble(prices[i].close));
            Chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(prices[i].date, Convert.ToDouble(prices[i].Volume));
             Chart1.Series[0].PostBackValue = "#INDEX";
            i--;
        }
        Chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "Date = #VALX \n Price = #VALY{C}";


        //while (i > 0)
        //{
        //    Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(prices[i].date, Convert.ToDouble(prices[i].low), Convert.ToDouble(prices[i].high), Convert.ToDouble(prices[i].Open), Convert.ToDouble(prices[i].close));
        //    Chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(prices[i].date, Convert.ToDouble(prices[i].Volume));
        //}

    }

    public void FlowChartfill()
    {
        string FileRead;
        string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        List<string> Flow = new List<string>();
        System.IO.StreamReader flowfile = new System.IO.StreamReader(path + "\\flow.txt");
        while ((FileRead = flowfile.ReadLine()) != null) //reads from file
        {
            Flow.Add(FileRead);
        }
        int i = Flow.Count - 1;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            Chart3.Series[0].Points.AddY(Convert.ToDouble(Flow[i].ToString()));
            i--;
        }

    }

    public DropDownList dateFill(DropDownList DropDown)
    {
        DropDown.Items.Add("Jan");
        DropDown.Items.Add("Feb");
        DropDown.Items.Add("Mar");
        DropDown.Items.Add("Apr");
        DropDown.Items.Add("May");
        DropDown.Items.Add("Jun");
        DropDown.Items.Add("Jal");
        DropDown.Items.Add("Aug");
        DropDown.Items.Add("Sep");
        DropDown.Items.Add("Oct");
        DropDown.Items.Add("Nov");
        DropDown.Items.Add("Dec");

        return DropDown;
    }

    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Chart1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Chart1_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)
    {


        // get series name and point index
       //string pointData = e.PostBackValue;
        string input = e.PostBackValue;
        ListBox1.Items.Add(input);

        //Series series = Chart1.Series[pointData[0]];
        //DataPoint point = series.Points[Int32.Parse(pointData[1])];

        //this.PointData.Value = e.PostBackValue;
        //this.PointValue.Text = point.YValues[0].ToString();





    }

    public void getChartData()
    {
        this.Chart1.Click += new ImageMapEventHandler(Chart1_Click);

        // direct using of PostBackValue
        foreach (Series series in this.Chart1.Series)
        {
            series.PostBackValue = "#INDEX";
        }

        // transfer of click coordinates. getCoordinates is a javascript function.
        string postbackScript = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this.Chart1, "chart:@");
        this.Chart1.Attributes["onclick"] = postbackScript.Replace("@'", "' + getCoordinates(event)");

    }
    //Date  Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Adj Close* 
    public class stock
    {
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string Open { get; set; }
        public string close { get; set; }
        public string high { get; set; }
        public string low { get; set; }
        public string Volume { get; set; }
        public string Adj_Close { get; set; }

    }

    public static class YahooFinance
    {
        public static List<stock> Parse(string csvData)
        {
            List<stock> prices = new List<stock>();

            string[] rows = csvData.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n');

            foreach (string row in rows)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row)) continue;

                string[] cols = row.Split(',');

                stock p = new stock();
                p.date = cols[0];
                p.Open = cols[1];
                p.high = cols[2];
                p.low = cols[3];
                p.close = cols[4];
                p.Volume = cols[5];
                p.Adj_Close = cols[6];

                prices.Add(p);
            }

            return prices;
        }
    }
}
```

}